# Find all (n,m,p) such that $n^{2}-5p^{m}=1$

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers

We have to find all solutions to $n^{2}-5p^{m}=1$ where m, n are naturals and p is prime.
So far we have found 3 solutions:
n=4,m=1,p=3;
n=6,m=1,p=7;
n=9,m=4,p=2

Not sure how to proceed. Are there any more solutions? Perhaps there are some restrictions applicable to m,n,p?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An important special case:  assume $p$ is odd.

Write your equation as $$n^2-1=5p^m\implies (n-1)(n+1)=5p^m$$

Then, $n$ is even,  $\gcd(n-1,n+1)=1$, and  we must have that  $p^m$ divides one or the other of $n\pm 1$.  But in that case the other factor must be either $5$ or $1$.  Thus $n=6$  or $n=4$.

Now say $p=2$.  Then $n$ must be odd, $\gcd(n-1,n+1)=2$, and $2^{m-1}$ must divide one of $n\pm 1$.  Again we get that the other factor must be $2$ or $2\times 5$.

Comment: We found those solutions using this method.

Comment: Well, by the argument I gave, those are all the solutions.  The only other one to check is $n=11$ and that one fails.